# Wordpress COOKIE_DOMAIN issue

Tags: wordpress

I use setcookie function like this

```
function jrl_menu_options() {

add_theme_page( 'Theme Setting Option', 'Theme Options', 'edit_theme_options', 'resto-theme-setting', 'resto_admin_options_page' );
    if( !isset($_COOKIE['resto_tab']) ) {
        setcookie('resto_tab', 'general', time()+86400, '/wordpress/wp-admin/', COOKIE_DOMAIN);
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'jrl_menu_options' );
```

It's no problem in localhost but when I deploy to a website, the cookie can't be created. I checked the COOKIE_DOMAIN and it was empty.

Thank in advance

Comment: try `str_replace('http://','',get_bloginfo('url'))` instead of `COOKIE_DOMAIN`

Comment: @user1134475 what is your site url ??

Comment: is '`COOKIE_DOMAIN`' defined ?

Comment: @user1134475 COOKIE_DOMAIN will be empty by default. Can you tell me what's your site url ?

Comment: the site url : webtoko.tk